# Insert Data Into another table during Registration in ASP.NET MVC5

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc, entity-framework

I understand that ASP.NET MVC creates a default table "AspNetUser" for storing users information during registration. How do I get Some of those data such as "Username" and store it in a seperate table during the registration process.

Am trying to get the "username" supplied by the user which is by default stored in the "AspNetUser Table" and store it in the "Student Table" also during the registration process

Register action

```
  // POST: /Account/Register
    [HttpPost]
    [AllowAnonymous]
    [ValidateAntiForgeryToken]
    public async Task<ActionResult> Register(RegisterViewModel model)
    {

        if (ModelState.IsValid)
        {

        StudentEntities db = new StudentEntities();

        var student = new Student
       {
          Name = model.Username     
       };
           db.Student.Add(Student);
           db.SaveChanges();

            var user = new ApplicationUser() { UserName = model.UserName };
            var result = await UserManager.CreateAsync(user, model.Password);
            if (result.Succeeded)
            {
                await SignInAsync(user, isPersistent: false);
                return RedirectToAction("Welcome", "Home");
            }
            else
            {
                AddErrors(result);
            }
        }

        // If we got this far, something failed, redisplay form
        return View(model);
    }
```

This doesn't seem to work

This doesn't seem to work

```
  StudentEntities db = new StudentEntities();

        var student = new Student
       {
          Name = model.Username     
       };
           db.Student.Add(Student);
           db.SaveChanges();
```

Comment: You probably need to expand more on **why** this doesn't work for you.

Comment: My "StudentEntities" which is for my student table is not being recognized

Comment: @OscarAnazodo What errors are you getting? Is is possible that your student model isnt valid? I.e are there more required fields?

Answer (score 0):

If you are using MVC5, it means you are using identity2. So It is better to use that to get user details. The best approach is doing this:
Add the following using statement.

```
using Microsoft.AspNet.Identity;
```

You can now get more methods from the HttpContext.User.Identity.

```
var UserName = User.Identity.GetUserName();
var UserId = User.Identity.GetUserId();
```

Be noted that identity usually uses email as username. But you can change it anyway.

Comment: While I have the UserName, How do I insert it into my "Student Table"?. And It should be done, during Registration inside the Register Action.

Comment: what is your problem adding UserName on  student table?